# Programmatically "clicking" a website link with C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to click a link within a website using C# and I am having difficulty getting it to work. Within the IF statement, I am able to get the message box to work once "Cert" is found but I am unable to actually click it with the InvokeMember. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML:

```html
<div class="resource myapps-myfolder" title="Cert" isfolder="true" folder-path="Main/Cert">
    <div class="myapps-icon-background"></div>
    <a class="myapps-icon" href="#">
        <img iconid="" src="uiareas/Store/media/FolderClosed32.png" alt="" class="iconImage">
    </a>
    <div class="myapps-name">Cert</div>
</div>
```

C#

```html
private void btnCert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var links = wbCerner.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");

    foreach (HtmlElement link in links)
    {
        if (link.GetAttribute("title").Equals("Cert"))
        { 
            link.InvokeMember("click");
        }

        // MessageBox.Show("Test");
    }
   }
```